# For Spring Boor 2.0+ , what is the value of "spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect" for SQL serve 2012?

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, sql-server-2012, spring-data-jpa

Note: "org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" isnot working

Comment: *isnot working* is not an error description. What does it means? Any error?

Comment: "2018-08-28 20:00:56 - GenerationTarget encountered exception accepting command : Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
"org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement

Comment: Add the complete stacktrace to your question not as comment

Comment: `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Cannot drop the table 'connections_master', because it does not exist or you do not have permission` is the root cause from your stacktrace. Check your database configuration and the permissions of your user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this.

set spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto =update

Hope it helps. :)